# Youtube V3 API - Retrieving content details part of channel resource results in 'operation is not valid due to the current state of the object'

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube V3 API nuget package for C#, and I am experiencing a JSON issue when Retrieving the contentDetails part of the channel resource.

Is there currently a bug in the API causing server side 500 errors?

Here is my code for the implementation.
The error is happening when I call this line of code:

`var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Snippet>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var videoList = new List<Snippet>();
        
        // Create the service
        var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString(),
            ApiKey = _apiKey
        });

        var channelsListRequest = service.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.Mine = true;
        
        // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
        var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
        {
            // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
            // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            
            var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
            
            var nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                var playlistItemsListRequest = service.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                {
                    // Print information about each video.
                    // Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                    videoList.Add(new Snippet()
                    {
                        Title = playlistItem.Snippet.Title
                    });
                }

                nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
            }
        }

        return videoList;
    }
```

Here is the result of running the method using a controller and postman...

I am using a snippet I found on the Youtube API documentation for samples.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteNumberWithCustomHandling(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonNumberHandling handling)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:7072
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Postman-Token: 809fd2c7-2fed-4c67-a01a-151d35b45241
```

Any help on this would be appreciated..

Comment: I only work with URLs and it works quite fine. Maybe having a look to [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) may interest you.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison , I'll give it a go! Thanks!